# IronPython - Different Ouputs from Script and Executable

Tags: windows, registry, ironpython

I created a small IronPython Script to list all Installed Software from a Windows PC.

```
import _winreg

def subkeys(key):
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            subkey = _winreg.EnumKey(key, i)
            yield subkey
            i+=1
        except:
            break

def traverse_registry_tree(key=_winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"), tabs=0):
    output = []
    for k in subkeys(key):
        meep = _winreg.OpenKey(key,k)
        if _winreg.QueryValueEx(meep,"DisplayName")[0] == None:
            string = str(k)
        else:
            string = str(_winreg.QueryValueEx(meep,"DisplayName")[0])
        output.append('\t'*tabs + string)
        traverse_registry_tree(k, tabs+1)
    output.sort()
    return output

output_file = open("output.txt",'w')
for line in traverse_registry_tree():
    tmp = line + '\n'
    output_file.write(tmp)
output_file.close()
```

After compling it with the following Options:

```
/main:wmi_test.py /out:test /embed /standalone /target:winexe
```

I generated the output.txt from the executable and the output.txt from the script. There is however a big difference between them:
http://www.diffchecker.com/wfbh79af

Here is a screenshot from "Uninstall Software" in the Windows Configuration Center:
http://jschpp.de/software.png

Could you help me to understand why there is such a big discrepancy.

I am using IronPython 2.7 on Windows 7 Professional x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say script, I assume you mean using `ipy.exe wmi_test.py`. The `ipy.exe` shipped with ironpython is a 32-bit executable (for various reasons); the executables built with `pyc.py` are AnyCPU, which means 64-bit for you. Windows has different registries for 32 and 64 bit programs.

An easy way to check that this is the case is to run the script with `ipy64.exe` instead and compare the results.

Comment: Yes that was the problem.
Sorry for my late answer I was out of Office.